# Split Python dict data by newline argument '\n'

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dict data that I obtain through a POST using javascript. The dict data is held in the variable 'commands' and the data in commands looks like this:

`{flightplantext': 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'}`

I want to store this data in a new dict/list in python in the following format:

`{'takeoff', 'up_80', 'down_80', 'land'}`

Essentially i want to split each command by the `\r\n` parts, make it lowercase, and put an underscore if there is a space in between a command and number.

I'm very new to Python and would appreciate any and all. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: So are you getting it as string or json ? if its data (in proper json format) you can do json.loads(data) it will give you `dict` and you can extract data.

Answer (score 0):

if you can extract string from data which you are getting from javascript.

```
data = commands.get('flightplantext') # data = 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'
```

So you `data` will be string as mentioned below

```
'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'.lower().replace(" ","_").split("\r\n")
```

output will be

```
['takeoff', 'up_80', 'down_80', 'land']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` with a list comprehension to generate a dictionary, we can try:

```py
inp = 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'
output = re.findall(r'(.*?)\r\n(.*?)(?:\r\n|$)', inp)
output = [[y.lower().replace(" ", "_") for y in x] for x in output]
d = dict(output)
print(d)  # {'down_80': 'land', 'takeoff': 'up_80'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your commands variable is a `dict`, this is what you're looking for:

```py
raw = commands["flightplantext"]                 # Get the value
parts = [p.lower() for p in raw.split("\r\n")]   # Split it
# Convert to dict
final = dict(zip(parts[::2], [i.replace(" ", "_") for i in parts[1::2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there is more than one key in `commands` dictionary:

```
commands = {'flightplantext': 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'}
result = {}
for k,v in commands.items():
    result[k] = commands[k].lower().replace(' ', '_').split('\r\n')
```

the result is

```
>>> result
{'flightplantext': ['takeoff', 'up_80', 'down_80', 'land']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
inp_dict = {'flightplantext': 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'}

out_list = []
for key,val in inp_dict.items():
    temp_str = val
    temp_str1 = temp_str.split("\r\n")#list
    for item in temp_str1:
        item1 = item.lower()
        item2 = item1.replace(" ","_")
        out_list.append(item2)
print(out_list)
```

output: ['takeoff', 'up_80', 'down_80', 'land']

Answer (score 0):

To get the final output as a list, here is what you can do:

```
commands = {'flightplantext': 'TAKEOFF\r\nUP 80\r\nDOWN 80\r\nLAND'}

temp_list_lowercase = ((commands.get('flightplantext')).lower()).splitlines()

# Using replace on each of the item present in the list to replace spaces with an underscore
final_list = [list_item.replace(" ", "_") for list_item in temp_list_lowercase]
print(final_list)
```